# How to predict at which day a value will be reached?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like the following:

```
Day  | Number  
1    |  2  
2    |  2.5  
3    |  3.5  
4    |  5  
5    |  7  
6    |  8  
7    |  10  
8    |  11  
9    |  13  
10   |  15  
11   |  12
```

Most of the time the numbers increase alongside the days, but sometimes they decrease instead.  I would like to know at which day the value of number will be a certain number. For example, I would like to know at which day the value of Number will reach 100.

Is this possible? I've tried using the FORECAST function, but when I lower the value of number and increase the number of days, the predicted day lowers, where if I understand correctly it should increase instead.

Comment: I forgot to add that sometimes the numbers do decrease even if the days increase (for the most part the numbers increase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step1. Use forecast

You need to lock the first calls in a `FORECAST` formula:

`=FORECAST(A17,B$2:B16,A$2:A16)`

Use `$` sign to lock the second row.

[image]

## Step2. Find the position of a day in a forecast

Please try:

`=INDEX(sort(A2:B,2,0), MATCH(C1,sort(B2:B,1,0),-1), 1)`

where C1 = 100 (your number)

[image]

The formula will sort the range twice and will work even if the number **does not grow** as the days increase.

Answer (score 2):

With your target `Number` in B13, please try in A13:

```
=FORECAST(B13,A$2:A12,B$2:B12)
```

[image: SO47463164 example]

You don't show the formula you tried so what was wrong with it is just a guess but maybe your `x`s and `y`s were 'the wrong way round'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use function slope to calculate the day. Slope is the amount number will increase for each day. When C2 is edited, this script will calculate the day for the number you you enter. Enter the target number in C2. In F2 put =slope(B2:B12,A2:A12). The custom menu has a reset.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Reset', [ 
     { name: 'Reset', functionName: 'reset' }
    ])}
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.source.getSheetName()
  var cell=e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var find=s.getRange("C2").getValue()
  var slope=s.getRange("F2").getValue()
Answer=0
if(sheet=="Sheet1" && cell=="C2"){
for (var i=0;i<100;i++){
  var Answer=Answer+1
  var test=Math.round(slope*Answer)
if(test>=find){
 s.getRange("D2").setValue(Answer);
    break; 
}}}}
function reset(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  s.getRange("C2").setValue(0) 
  s.getRange("D2").setValue(0);
}
```

Here is a test spreadsheet you can copy and try. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1inmd2Lc1aOfVL7POKye6p2OQHsloJryISgdqNMowW90/edit?usp=sharing